# MYSQL: Insert a value into a new table, while deleting it from the old one?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables, sql-insert, delete-row

Is this possible? For some context I am working with temporary tables and would like to shift values around. I am simply wondering if I can insert a value from a column of one table into the column of a new table, while deleting the original value from the first table (if that makes sense).

Table 1

```
   |id|    |Column_with_value|
    ---------------------------------       
    1       | blah                  |        
    ---------------------------------
```

Table 2

```
(empty)
```

---

### becomes:

Table 1

```
(empty)
```

Table 2

```
   |id|    |Column_with_value|
    ---------------------------------       
    1       | blah                  |        
    ---------------------------------
```

Comment: Not in the same query. Why do you want to delete the value from `Table 1`?

Comment: Requires 1 insert, 1 delete. If you find yourself doing this maybe table1 and table2 should be a single table with a flag to differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know one single operation which can do this. But there is really no need to put that into one operation as long as it stays in one transaction:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM table1 …;
UPDATE table2 …;
DELETE FROM table1 …;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger on table 1 which listens for delete statements.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_insert_table2_trigger`     
  AFTER DELETE ON `table1`     
  FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.Column_with_value)
END
```

With OLD you can access the values of the deleted row.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER Remove_Old
BEFORE DELETE ON Table_1
FOR EACH ROW
Insert Into Table_2
SELECt * From Table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving data between tables costs, complicates schema, and increases maintenance. Probably better if you had a single table with all of the data, with an additional column to tag it accordingly.

However

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (id, column)
    SELECT id, column from tbl_2 where id=1;
DELETE FROM tbl1 where id=1;
```

Or if you just want to move everything from a full table to an empty table, try

```
RENAME TABLE tbl_1 TO tbl_2
```